# Combine different alerts for the same expression in prometheus alert

Tags: prometheus

For example, I have an prometheus alert:

```
  - alert: ProductOfferRateAlert
    expr: sum(increase(product_offer_counter)) by (type, country) < 100
    for: 5m
    labels:
      level: P2
      frequency: every 5m
    annotations:
      summary: "product offer rate was too low"
      description: "product {{$labels.type}} from country {{$labels.conuntry}} offer rate was too low"
```

This alert is clear and useful, but we will see too many alert like:

```
product A from country A offer rate was too low
product B from country B offer rate was too low
product C from country C offer rate was too low
product D from country D offer rate was too low...
```

Can we let it only alert once everyday, and show all information we need like:

```
[A-A, B-B, C-C, D-D] offer rate was too low
```

rather than showing seperate record?

Thanks in advance!

The reason for asking this question is to get some tips to optimize our alert and make it more concise and intuitive.

Comment: Don't think it's possible to do this kind of aggregation through query itself, nor it would be wise. Consider handling this through [a grouping mechanism](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/alertmanager/#grouping), and then providing a custom notification template to format data as you want.